# Extra Padding From Bottom Of Div After jQuery Accordian Script Is Actived

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, jquery-ui-accordion

I have designed a website that consists of the "body", a "container" to hold and center a "content" div on the page. The height of the "content" and "container" divs is set to 100%, I have also added an Accordian jQuery Script within the "content" div. Now in Google Chrome, when I activate the div that uses the jQuery Accordian Script, it show the div as expected. The page expands in height, and follows the height: 100% attribute which is coded within the External Cascading Style Sheet. But, (here's the problem), in Google Chrome, it adds extra space below the "container" div, and which shows a problem within the coding, whether it be in the XHTML 1.0 Strict, and or the CSS document. Or it could possibly be in the JavaScript.

Both of the XHTML 1.0 Strict and CSS are validated, except for one error in the XHTML document, which has already been fixed without re-uploading it to the server, which does not affect the problem any.

The specified jQuery Accordian Div is located where the image "Click To Inquire" is specified.

You can view the page at: http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/thecommonwealth/index.html

You can view the css at: http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/thecommonwealth/style.css

You can view the JavaScript at: http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/thecommonwealth/javascript.js

If you do not have Google Chrome, and or use Internet Explorer, Opera, Apple Safari, and or Mozilla Firefox. You can view the problem I am running into as an image

[image]

Look below the red, and then the black right below it. Hence, the extra spacing.

It would be very appreciative is someone were to help me with this issue,
Thank you very much,
Aaron Brewer

Comment: +1 for a good description.  To be honest, I'm not sure why you think you need the 100% height attribute.  Your content requires scrolling which makes it all a moot point.  What happens when you remove `height: 100%;` ?

Comment: Also, I again strongly stress, that you bring the HTML into full compliance even if it makes no difference to this issue.  The fact that this is working in all browsers including Safari (Webkit) but not in Chrome (Webkit) is very odd.

Comment: @Sparky672: Thank you for the +1 Reputation. I want the height to be 100% for when the content in the container ends, the background will still end at the bottom of the window. I removed it, and it did nothing at all different lol. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Spary672: It is up to full compliance now, both the XHTML document and the CSS document. Maybe I may have poorly coded jQuery Script possibly?

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea what the problem is, haven't invested enough time to understand. Although it goes away when I add the following to the css

```css
#wrapper {overflow:auto}
```

Not sure how satisfying a "this solves it with no explanation" is :)

Comment: @davin: Thank you very much, I appreciate the solution very much. I do not know how that may have fixed the problem, but like you said, it does... and I am quite happy with it. lol. Thank you.

Comment: @Aaron, a pleasure. I hope the layout continues to behave well.

Comment: I think it's a combination of things.  For one, the 100% height describes the size relative to the container... in this case, the window. You're telling it you want it to be 100% but the actual content is more like 300% of the window size.  Somehow `overflow:auto;` overcomes whatever Chrome doesn't like about that part of your code.  Additionally, I believe that "auto" is the default behavior of "overflow" so perhaps you just found a Chrome quirk here.

Comment: @Sparky, it's not, default is `visible`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow

Comment: @davin.  Thanks.  It's certainly odd that Chrome was the only thing rendering it differently.

Comment: @Sparky672, @davin: Thank you both so much, I appreciate all of the help you have given me, advice, and such. I have learned a lot due to this issue lol. Thank you.